# mapStateToProps change props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to use React-Redux, because I love the system of actions. I find, this is an easy way to process all status in actions. Loading, Success and Failure status. I following a tutorial and I finish him with success. I got react-thunk, store, reducer, actions, payloads etc.

But in my case, when I finishing to dispatch my API call in my component, I give transfer the state in the props like this. Then I recover my status and I can display the datas in an board.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  datas: state.datas.items,
  loading: state.datas.loading,
  error: state.datas.error,
  deleted: state.datas.deleted
});
```

The problem is the props is immutable and I doing this for differents components then the props datas changes. How can I recover the state.datas.items and store this in the state of the component ?

Comment: Why would you need to store a global app state within a component, you're pulling in the current global state from `mapStateToProps` to be usable within the component?

Comment: @OliverHeward I dispatch API and I want to Return the state of my actions in my component. Here mapStateToProps help me to get the datas but that store in the props.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what your direction is with this. But if you are wishing to then access this data being stored as props, you need to use either `this.props.datas` or `props.datas` depending on your set up. Try logging the `this.props.datas` being returned and if that works, pass that to the state of the component, but be aware if this component unmounts, or remounts the state will be set back to what redux is mapping to the component from the global app state.

Comment: @OliverHeward But its not bad to change the state of the props in each calls of my API ?  I have some CRUDS and I change the state of the props in each calls. It's bad no ?